# How to draw routes in maps , ios6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have been drawing routes in iOS5, but as the app has to be upgraded to iOS6, it does not allow to draw routes between coordinate locations . I have searched a lot, but ended up in vain. Can anyone help me on which api to use in iOS6 since google maps doesnt support anymore ???

EDIT : I have used Google iOS SDK previously to plot the routes which will auto take care of the polylines. As far as I have searched, i will be able to redirect to browser to show routes and navigation. But i need to draw this in-app [ iOS6 ]. Does iOS6 automatically does the routing, if so can u pls share some code to get a gist of it. This code sample I used it in iOS5 using google maps

```
// over lay map to draw route
    routeOverlayView = [[UICRouteOverlayMapView alloc] initWithMapView:routeMapView];
    diretions = [UICGDirections sharedDirections];

    UICGDirectionsOptions *options = [[UICGDirectionsOptions alloc] init];
//setting travel mode to driving
    options.travelMode = UICGTravelModeDriving;
    [diretions loadWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint options:options];

// Overlay polylines
    UICGPolyline *polyline = [directions polyline];
    NSArray *routePoints = [polyline routePoints];
        NSLog(@"routePoints %@",routePoints);

    [routeOverlayView setRoutes:routePoints];
```

Comment: How are you drawing your routes? Because although Apple changed map providers in iOS 6, the way polylines are drawn is pretty much the same. Perhaps provide some code for us to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did route in my application. I used The Google Geocoding API (used for iOS 6 only)  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Something like this:

```
- (void) sendRequestForLat: (CGFloat) lat lon: (CGFloat) lon
{
    NSString* request;
    NSInteger zoom = 12;

    NSString* location = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", lat, lon];

    NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f,%f", myLat, myLon];
    request = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"saddr=%@&daddr=%@&zoom=%i&directionsmode=walking", location, daddr, zoom];

    NSString* typeMapsApp = isGoogleMapsAppPresent ? @"comgoogle" : @"";

    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@maps://?%@", typeMapsApp, request];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a third party piece of code to do your route drawing, rather than using MapKit itself. The library you're using (which I found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)) hasn't been updated for two years.

I'd recommend you move away from that library to something more current. If you want you could consider using Google's iOS Map SDK, which supports iOS 6 ([link here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)). You could combine this with Google's Directions API to draw polylines directly onto the map. Or you could stick with `MKMapView`, and again draw directly onto the map with polylines.

It's not that iOS has changed how it draws polylines onto a map - it's that the third-party code you're using is out of date.

Comment: How to combine directions api with google sdk to draw route for driving mode, Can u provide any code link or some sample code ?